# OpenGL Texture Stretching

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I'm trying to attach a texture to a cube. Currently, the texture is stretching.

I know it's an issue with my texture coordinates but I cannot figure out what.

For all of the vertices positions (`x,y,z`), I made the texture coordinate (`x,y`).

```
float [] texCoords = new float [2*allPoints.size()];
int index= 0;
for(int i = 0; index< allPoints.size()-1; i=i+2){
           texCoords[i] = (float)allPoints.get(index).getX();
           texCoords[i+1] = (float)allPoints.get(index).getY();
           index++;
}
```

**glTexParameters:**

```
gl2.glTexParameteri( GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL.GL_NEAREST);
gl2.glTexParameteri( GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL.GL_NEAREST);
gl2.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL.GL_REPEAT);
gl2.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL.GL_REPEAT);
```

**Current output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texture coordinates in OpenGL are scaled 0-1, if you go past that boundary, according to your parameter of `GL_REPEAT` for `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`.

I don't know about the organization of your `allPoints` list, but for a cube, you're going to have multiple unique texture coordinates per vertex, so you're going to need to duplicate your vertices. If you draw it out by hand or think about it, a texture coordinate of `1` on a vertex also has to be `0` for an adjacent face.

Each face should have the following texture coordinates:

```
(0, 1)--(1, 1)
|            |
|            |
|            |
(0, 0)--(1, 0)
```

Now think about the faces on a cube, the `(1, 1)` point is the `(0, 1)` point of the adjacent face. Duplicate your vertices to fix that issue.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I changed the texture coordinates accordingly but it still looks stretched out. (http://i.imgur.com/QIYqC.png). allPoints is all of the points in the tessellation of the cube. Does it matter that the cube's vertices are from -0.5 -> 0.5? Thanks!

Comment: Texture coordinates are independent of vertices. It looks like you've got some texture coordinates mismatched with vertices. Like for the top face, it looks like the bottom left and right coords are flipped. Just mess with the values until you get the right values in the right spots.